# HTTP get request tcl

Tags: url, https, tcl

I am working in tcl 8.6 and I am trying to send a get request to google. 
Here is the following code I have used:

My question is how can I make a get request to google using tcl?

```
package require http
::http::config -useragent "Mozilla/5.0"

set url http://www.google.com

set http [::http::geturl $url]
set html [::http::data $http]

return $html
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Sorry, my question is how can I make a get request to google using tcl?

Comment: That *is* how you do it... however, `http://www.google.com` is just a placeholder address: when you try to get it you instead get a reference to the address Google thinks you should connect to instead. In my case, it's a longurl in the Swedish domain. There is a bit of code that lets you go through a redirect, I'll see if I can dig it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this wrapper for `http::geturl`:

```
package require uri
proc geturl_followRedirects {url args} {
    array set URI [::uri::split $url]
    for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
        set token [::http::geturl $url {*}$args]
        if {![string match {30[1237]} [::http::ncode $token]]} {return $token}
        array set meta [string tolower [set ${token}(meta)]]
        if {![info exist meta(location)]} {
            return $token
        }
        array set uri [::uri::split $meta(location)]
        unset meta
        if {$uri(host) eq {}} {set uri(host) $URI(host)}
        # problem w/ relative versus absolute paths
        set url [::uri::join {*}[array get uri]]
    }
}
```

The command is due to Donal Fellows and Keith Vetter, [original](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11831). I updated it a bit to take advantage of Tcl 8.6. It also checks up to 5 times instead of indefinitely. I also incorporated a suggestion by Paul Walton.

The command returns a `http` token just like `http::geturl` does, and takes the same arguments as that command does.

ivan73 notes that this code has the limitation that redirection urls will be mangled by the case conversion. It can be argued that urls seldom use uppercase letters, but it's still a limitation. I suppose that instead of

```
        array set meta [string tolower [set ${token}(meta)]]
        if {![info exist meta(location)]} {
            return $token
        }
        array set uri [::uri::split $meta(location)]
        unset meta
```

one could use

```
        set location [lmap {k v} [set ${token}(meta)] {
            if {[string match -nocase location $k]} {set v} continue
        }]
        if {$location eq {}} {
            return $token
        }
        array set uri [::uri::split $location]
```

for a case-insensitive match that preserves the values (and keys) of the meta structure.

Comment: In `array set meta [string tolower [set ${token}(meta)]]` you are making also Location value (URL where you are redirected) lowercase so code will not work always because URL can be case sensitive. This is very subtle bug. Works for redirect to `Location: http://example.com/somefile` doesn't work for `Location: http://example.com/someFILE`.

Comment: @ivan73: thank you for pointing this out. I have amended the answer with a hopefully sufficient workaround.